# extract full path of hyperlink of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

how do you extract the full path of a hyperlink in a cell, ive been given a workbook with a list of generated hyperlinks cells and im trying to extract the full path

when i select a cell and press CTRL+K it just shows the path as **../folder/filename** also when i use a vba code below it just shows the same value

what i would like is the full path like "C:\Users\username\folder\filename"

```
Range("C4") = Cells(4, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

i changed the property hyperlink base to 'C:' and then i generated a sample hyperlink and got a '\Users\username\folder\filename' but the earlier cells with hyperlink has still the same result

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any method of properties you can make use of to get the full path.

what you can consider doing is, if the hyperlink is an Excel workbook, you can open it up and then make use of the FullName property, then close the workbook.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, fullpath As String

For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        fullpath = wb.FullName
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
Next wb
```

Comment: it will be a bit more complicated if it is files like PDF, other application like Chrome, SAP and etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not an excel file, it is a pdf file